# Joomla split testing using static HTML pages

Tags: php, html, joomla, ab-testing

Doing an A/B split test on a Joomla install with Google Web Optimizer. The elements that are changing in the split test variations live in the header/menu of the site and not in the content areas.

Because of this, I need to use static HTML pages for each variation and I'm having an issue getting links on these variation pages to work properly in the context of the rest of the Joomla website.

For example, a user needs to get to the page www.thesite.com/contact-us/estimate-form.html in order for Google Web Optimizer to count that visit as a successful conversion, but because of how Joomla dynamically handles links there is no actual estimate-form.html page that lives in the folder /contact-us despite that URL being displayed in the browser.

As it stands now, Joomla has me stuck in a redirect loop, probably because it can't find the estimate-form.html page, that keeps dropping me to the top level of the website. This obviously breaks any attempt at conversion testing and I'm wondering how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer your question.  But at my company we use:

http://www.optimizely.com/

This is not an advertisement and have never worked for this company or received money from this company.  This made our AB testing a breeze.  We use wordpress for our company websites.

They have free trials if you would like to test it first:

https://optimizely.appspot.com/pricing

Comment: Should have added, I actually installed and am using this plugin to manage the Google conversion testing code: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/11274

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do static pages for any of this. You already have the correct extension installed to manage the tracking codes. You can put the tracking codes in modules, it does not have to go in the content area. The trick is making menu items for the original page and each of the variations so you can easily assign modules to each page to put the tracking codes in. Google doesn't care if a file exists in the file structure, it is looking for the tracking codes.

You might need to invest the $50 to get the pro version and support, but the Website Optimizer extension should do exactly what you are trying to do without having to make any static pages.

Look through the pro documentation here - http://www.pearl-group.com/optimizer-pro-documentation